# Add new strings between specific words of string

Tags: javascript

I want to add a string that was stored in one variable to existing string between specific words.

```
var String = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Title</title> <style></style></head><body> <p>Hello</p></body></html>'
var string_to_add = 'p{background-color: red;}'
```

Now I want output as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Title</title> <style>p{background-color: red;}</style></head><body> <p>Hello</p></body></html>
```

Comment: If it is a HTML string why not convert it to HTML, and then convert back again after editing it using DOM methods?

Comment: Because I will render that string in Vue JS. So no need to convert a string into HTML. @evolutionxbox

Comment: bad idea using `String` as variable name. In wrong scope will conflict with global `String` Show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: Please see my answer and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```js
String.replace("<style>", "<style>" + string_to_add);
```